Is it possible to add my dapp as a safe app without iframe?
I want to add GammaSwap as a Safe app. However, due to a vulnerability, we disabled use of <iframe> because of an attack vector that allows anyone to embed our site and trick users into clicking links that eventually drains connected wallets and/or adds malware into their device.
We do this by adding the response header like so
"X-Frame-Options": "DENY",

With that being said, would this make it impossible to add our dapp to the safe app registry? If so, are there any alternatives?

Yes, setting "X-Frame-Options": "DENY" will prevent your dApp from being embedded in an <iframe>, which is needed for integration with the Safe{Wallet} app registry.
You could try either:

Using Content Security Policy (CSP) with frame-ancestors: Instead of completely disabling iframe embedding, you can specify which domains are allowed to embed your dApp.
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://app.safe.global


This header allows your dApp to be embedded only on your own domain and the Safe{Wallet} domain. It prevents other sites from embedding your dApp, mitigating the risk of clickjacking attacks while still allowing integration with Safe{Wallet}.

You could also create a dApp on your own domain and use the Safe{Core} SDK to connect your users with their Safes, but this will be out of the Safe Apps context.

Hope it helps! Best, Louis

Thank you! I was also thinking of this alternative as well :)
